# Tomcat6 Decompressing GZip Request

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, gzip, deflate, request-filtering

Since **Tomcat** has the option to compress its response to **GZip**.

Is there a way to configure **Tomcat 6** to **decompress** gzipped requests without putting it behind an **Apache** server with **mod_deflate** enabled, or creating a GZip filter on the application level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned out to use a [2Way](http://predic8.com/gzip-compression-filter.htm) filter on the application level to compress and decompress
I removed the tomcat configuration